# Progmatically Setting Heading in MKMapView

Tags: ios, mkmapview

I would like my MKMapView to rotate based on heading which is set progmatically.

All I have been able to do is rotate the view itself but then of course the street names, etc are upside down.

Can someone please help me out?

Comment: Do you mean mkmapview?  Might want to update your tags - mkmapview and mapkit would be good.

Comment: Yes sorry. That's what I meant.

Answer (score 2):

It does not appear to me that you can manually set the heading for the map view.  You can set the behavior that rotates the map view to follow the user's current compass heading, though:

```
[mapView setUserTrackingMode:MKUserTrackingModeFollowWithHeading
                    animated:YES];
```

Comment: Yes I found this but the position/heading/altitude data is coming from a PC game though.

Comment: If you use this, then you can't control the programatic zoom level. It's a bug in MapKit.

Answer (score 1):

This question is old so many things have changed until. But there is definetly the possibility like so in swift:

```
mapView.camera.heading = 0
```